# Difference between filter and filterNot in kotin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list in which I am filtering by `name` and `summary` which is coming from the server and it can be `null` or `empty`. I used `filter` which is working fine.

**MovieDetails**

```
data class MovieDetails(
    val name: String? = null,
    val iconUrl: String? = null,
    val summary: String? = null,
)
```

**main**

```
fun main() {
    filterMovieDetails(listOf(MovieDetails(summary = "name")))
}

private fun filterMovieDetails(itemList: List<MovieDetails>) {
    val result = itemList
        .asSequence()
        .filter { !it.name.isNullOrEmpty() && !it.summary.isNullOrEmpty() }
        .map {
            MovieItemModel(
                it.name.orEmpty(),
                it.iconUrl.orEmpty(),
                it.summary.orEmpty(),
            )
        }.toList()
    println(result)
}
```

this is working fine. If your `name` and `summary` is **null** or **empty** then it returns `emptyList()`. Above code returns `[]` because my `name` is **null**.

**Problem**

When I change my `filter` to `filterNot` like this

```
 .filterNot { it.name.isNullOrEmpty() && it.summary.isNullOrEmpty() }
```

it gives me output

```
[MovieItemModel(name=, icon=, summary=name)]
```

which is wrong.

So what is wrong in here?

Comment: change `&&` to `||` in filterNot. Just a simple negation of two statements! Right now you are requiring the elements to be both with empty or null name and with empty or null summary. But you need only one of this conditions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a boolean logic error - you always have to watch out for this when trying to invert your logic!

Both of these functions take a predicate, and keep items depending on the result. `filter` keeps them if the predicate returns *true*, `filterNot` if it returns *false*.

So here's your first predicate:

```
!it.name.isNullOrEmpty() && !it.summary.isNullOrEmpty()
```

This returns *true* if `name` **and** `summary` are both non-null and non-empty. You're using `filter`, so you take anything that matches this check.

The second predicate:

```
it.name.isNullOrEmpty() && it.summary.isNullOrEmpty()
```

This returns *true* if `name` and `summary` **are both empty**. Because you're using `filterNot`, you take **anything that doesn't match this**. So that includes items where **only one** of them is null or empty, as well as items where neither of them are.

So what you want is this:

```
!(it.name.isNullOrEmpty() || it.summary.isNullOrEmpty())
```

The `!` being handled by `filterNot` in this case, but that's the boolean equivalent.

*!A && !B == !(A || B)*

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem to replace from `&&`  to `||`. It works.

```
.filterNot { it.name.isNullOrEmpty() || it.summary.isNullOrEmpty() }
```